# Mule resource access

Tags: mule

I have an xml file in src/main/resources. I also have a folder called input at the root level of the project. When the xml file is copied to input my File endpoint picks it up to process. This works fine in Anypoint Studio when I copy paste the file to input.

I then exported the app and deployed it to Mule EE standalone 3.7.0. Now I want a shell script to start Mule and move the xml file to the input folder. When I call

```
mv /usr/local/opt/mule/apps/as2-x12-send-v201509201932/resources/po.xml  /usr/local/opt/mule/apps/as2-x12-send-v201509201932/output/po.xml
```

I get back:

```
No such file or directory
```

This is due to the project being zipped in the WEB-INF directory.

How can I automate the moving of the file so it gets processed using a shell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's super bad practice to have input/output directories inside the path of your deployed application.

Pick another location, outside of Mule, like for example somewhere under [`/var/lib`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#VARLIBVARIABLESTATEINFORMATION).